# How do I copy a file from mobile device to desktop?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

From a Windows mobile app (VB.Net), I want to be able to copy a file from the mobile device to a desktop (during a direct connection to the desktop). Is there a quick and simple way to do this?

Comment: do you mean Windows Phone mobile app? what kind of mobile device? What have you tried ?

Comment: Edited to mention Windows. It's a device running Windows CE. Not a phone, though. I'm not sure what to call it-- some industrial handheld.

Comment: `File.Copy` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: File.Copy definitely will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`RAPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee497054.aspx).  There's [a managed wrapper for version 1 here](http://rapi.codeplex.com/) and [a managed wrapper for version 2 here](http://rapi2.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that OpenNETCF is for the desktop application? Coz I need one for the mobile app, running on WinCE.

Comment: No Yves, some of the OpenNetCF products (Smart Device Framework) are not for desktop, they are used on mobile.